# How to raise ValueError with Regular Expressions in python

Tags: python-3.x, exception

My function should parse the email only if it exactly matches the email specification. If the input is not a valid email address, the function should raise a ValueError. For the example 'x @hpcgarage.org', my function only returns None instead of raising a ValueError.

```
def parse_email(s):
try:
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-zA-Z])([-\S\w._+]+)@([-\S\w._+]+)([a-zA-Z])\b')
    matches = pattern.finditer(s)
    for match in matches:
        #print(match.group(0))
        return (match.group(1)+match.group(2), match.group(3)+match.group(4))
except:
    print('here')
    raise ValueError
print(parse_email('x @hpcgarage.org'))
print(parse_email('what-do-you-know+not-much@gmail.com'))
```

output:

None

('what-do-you-know+not-much', 'gmail.com')

Comment: Your `except` doesn't catch anything because there is no exception raised within the `try` block. Just put your `raise ValueError` right after the `for` loop so that it will be raised if nothing gets `return`ed.

Comment: If the argument doesn't match the pattern then `matches` is an empty iterator and the loop body is never entered, that's **not** the same thing as throwing an error. You seem to be only expecting a single match, so it's not clear why you're using the loop to start with.